# Cannot connect google APIs project to any google+ page

Tags: google-plus

Hi I have a project created in Google APIs console , I cannot connect it with any google+ page,

It show the error "An error occurred while processing the request. Please try again." in the 'Connected Service' page in Google+ after I press the approve button. I have tried several google+ pages but all didn't work.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason for that and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @marcopo, do you still see this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Connecting your Google+ Page to your Google APIs Console project is a two-step process. You can see the full instructions at the bottom of the page at https://developers.google.com/+/features/analytics.

However, the basic process is to first tell the console project which Google+ Page will be connected, and then to go back to the Page and Request a connection to the project.

To see a demo, you can see the Google+ Platform Insights episode of Google+ Developers Live, where we connect a Google+ Page to enable additional analytics.  The demo begins around 2:15 at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpj9MVNGEl0.